# How to dynamically set tableView height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a hard time setting my `tableView` height according to it's content. My cells have dynamic heights and if I hard code an height for my table view I'm able to see that they are fine. Now my problem is:

- **My table view doesn't resize at the correct height according to my cells**
- **If I do not set a static height for the table view, the cells are not rendered**
- **BONUS ISSUE: I use SnapKit to make constraints and when I remake constraints to fit my table view height according to content size, it fires `viewDidLoad` as many times as I have cells***

All things being said here is some code:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    private var cellHeight: CGFloat? = UITableView.automaticDimension
    private var hasLoader: Bool = true
    lazy var tableView: UITableView! = UITableView()
    lazy var loadMoreButton: UIButton! = PrimaryButton(textKey: "actionSeeMore")
    lazy var emptyView: UILabel! = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        initActions()
        initLayout()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadList(appendItems: true)
    }

    func initLayout() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.view.addSubview(emptyView)
        self.view.addSubview(loadMoreButton)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.right.leading.trailing.top.equalToSuperview()
            if(self.hasLoader == true) {
                make.bottom.equalTo(self.loadMoreButton.snp.top).offset(-15)
            }
            print("PRINT TABLE HEIGHT", self.tableView.contentSize.height) // It's 0.0
            make.height.equalTo(1000) // Just trying things
        }
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        emptyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        emptyView.isHidden = true
        emptyView.textAlignment = .center
        emptyView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.right.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(8)
        }
        
        self.loadMoreButton.isHidden = true
        if(self.hasLoader == true) {
            self.loadMoreButton.isHidden = false
            loadMoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            loadMoreButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
                make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
                make.top.equalTo(tableView.snp.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func initActions() {
        loadMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loadMoreOnClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    func loadList(appendItems: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.apiClient.getList(completion: { _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    // Here I normally do tableView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in make.height.equalTo(self.tableView.contentSize.height) } which fires viewDidLoad many times (as much as I have cells)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func loadMore() {
        self.page += 1
        self.loadList(appendItems: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resourceList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        let currentResource = resourceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.setResource(resource: currentResource)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let resource = resourceList[indexPath.row]
        if (resource.getRouteParam() != "") {
            router.setRoute(routeName: resource.getRouteName(), routeParam: 
            resource.getRouteParam())
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

**I have omitted parts of the code for readability.**

Comment: `UITableView` is designed to reuse cells and allow them to be scrolled. If you have so few "rows" that you won't be scrolling, you may (probably would) be better off **not** using a table view.

Comment: What you mean by "so few rows" ? I have a lot of rows to display

Comment: If you have *"lots of rows to display"* why are you trying to change the table view height?

Comment: Because as I explained, nothing is showed when I don't do it

Comment: The "normal" layout is to have your table view height set to fill a certain amount of space. So... what are you doing with your layout that your table starts out without a size?

Comment: I'm using tableView inside a scroll view, that may be why this behaviour is occuring

Comment: *"I'm using tableView inside a scroll view"* ... yes, that is a problem. Your approach will make the table view -- if you have "lots of rows" -- absurdly tall and you lose the memory management of reusable cells. You probably should re-think your layout design.

Comment: Guess you're right, I'll rethink my layout then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following :

1. Declare a variable inside your `UIViewController` subclass like this.

```swift
private var contentSizeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

2. Inside `viewDidLoad()` or whenever your `myTableView` is set up, start observing contentSize changes.

```swift
contentSizeObservation = myTableView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new, changeHandler: { [weak self] (tv, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.myTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tv.contentSize.height
})
```

3. Do NOT Forget to clean this up in `deinit` call -

```swift
deinit {
    contentSizeObservation?.invalidate()
}
```

This approach will make sure that your `myTableView` is always as big in height as it's content.

Comment: What is "myTableViewHeightConstraint" ? Is it a variable or a build-in one ?

Comment: It's the height constraint that you add for managing your table view height, this is not a built-in one.

Comment: Your method seems to work well but it does fire viewDidLoad as many times as I have cells again... Is that a normal behaviour ?

Comment: + If I do not set an initial height value for my table view, it doesn't render cells so doesn't update contentSize

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is supposed to fire only once - initially when `UIViewController.view` is shown in the app. You should provide your tableView a minimum positive value for height like 20/40 so that it has a chance to call it's data source methods implementation AND based on that know how big it's content is going to be. If initially it's height is 0, then it won't call your data source implementation because it doesn't need to display anything. You have to make sure your data source implementations are called so tableView knows how big contentSize it's going to need to fit everything.